# ON DELETE SET NULL in postgres

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql

HI I'm new to postgresql environment so been lost for a while. I want to keep my data when parent entity is deleted. I want to know how to make 'ON DELETE SET NULL' for postgresql database. Please give me a clue.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q="ON+DELETE"+"SET+NULL"+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.postgresql.org%2Fdocs%2F ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`ON DELETE SET NULL` is a standard foreign key constraint option.

```
CREATE TABLE some_child (
    parent_id integer references parent(id) on delete set null
);
```

or:

```
ALTER TABLE some_child 
ADD CONSTRAINT parent_id_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) 
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

See [the documentation](https://www.google.com.au/search?q="ON+DELETE"+"SET+NULL"+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.postgresql.org%2Fdocs%2F).

In future posts make sure you include your PostgreSQL version and explain what you've already tried.