# Defer deletion of cascade objects in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a small DB with 10 tables all linked with Foreign Key (FK) relationships. Some of them uses Joined Table inheritance. All relationships have `cascade=all,delete` in the ORM. All FK are indexed. I use `SQLAlchemy`.

Deleting an object is long because there are many linked large objects which gets deleted in cascade. I have a basic UI which runs few operations in main thread. I'll look into deferring the deletion in background, and get a notification in the UI. But:

Is there a way to delete the main object only (fast) and defer the deletion of cascaded objects (slow) later on, like overnight or when the DB is idle? So that the operation *looks* faster from the user perspective?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [delete docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#delete) here.If you do not specify the delete cascade then the default behavior of sqlalchemy is it makes the childs orphans as they are dissociated from the parents. If that is the case it can work in your case if foreign key is set to Null and later you can run a simple query well db load is less to delete the orphans.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898274/on-delete-set-null-in-postgres) post can also help in clarifying.