# Prevent Foreign Key from Being Deleted on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, oracle

On PostgreSQL, how do I prevent value of foreign key from being deleted EVEN AFTER its referenced primary key is deleted?

**EVEN IF** I deleted an `account_number` primary key from the `bank_account` table, I still want to keep the `account_number` foreign key in the `payment_history` table, as shown below:

[image: My two tables]

How do I prevent FK `Account_Number` from being deleted in `payment_history` table even after I deleted its primary key in the `bank_account` table? Please help. Thanks!

Here's the code that I have used to create the two tables:

```
create table bank_account
(
    account_number int primary key, 
    bank_name varchar(40)
);

create table payment_history
(
    payment_history_id int primary key, 
    account_number int, 
    amount_paid decimal, 
    date date, 

    constraint account_number_fk 
        foreign key(account_number) references bank_account(account_number)
);
```

Comment: foreign keys maintain consistency between tables.  If you don't want consistency, you don't want foreign keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898274/on-delete-set-null-in-postgres

Comment: I still want the foreign key value even after the primary key is deleted. I don't want the foreign key to be set to null after the primary key is deleted.

Comment: The only way this works is if you don't delete the row in `bank_account`. This means a adding a field say `active boolean` and have it be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys always have the task of ensuring the integrity between 2 tables. By default, PostgreSQL will throw an error if the foreign key is defined and a key element is to be deleted. Alternatively you could set the foreign key to null. Since you don't want either action, nor do you want to ensure that the intrigue of the two tables remains, you don't want to use any property of the foreign key definition at this point. So the solution would be to omit the foreign key. Which is perfectly fine for historical data and does not speak against the normalization itself.

What you could do, however, would be to define a function that triggers the insert and thus ensures that at least when inserting into the history, the bank account exists. Should this also not meet your wishes / requirements, you must somehow create the data integrity itself.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_account_number_exists()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   -- If the account number doesn't exist in bank_account, raise an exception.
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bank_account WHERE account_number = NEW.account_number) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'account_number % does not exist in bank_account', NEW.account_number;
   END IF;

   -- If the account number exists, proceed with the insertion.
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the Trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER payment_history_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON payment_history
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_account_number_exists();
```